# Check if a set of variables have non-false values?

Tags: python

Many times in my Python code, I will find myself doing something like:

```
foo = something()
bar = something()
baz = something()

if not foo and not bar and not baz:
    raise SomeException
else:
    do_something(foo, bar, baz)
```

I want to know if there is a more Pythonic solution to check if the variable has a non-falsey value.

Comment: If you're checking if they exist at all, then you should catch `AttributeError`: `try: do_something(foo, bar, baz); except AttributeError: # handle`. That may not be what you're doing though.

Comment: @WaleedKhan -- or `NameError`

Comment: When speaking of variables, "are defined" generally means "is bound" (i.e. can be *accessed* without raising a NameError) - this is different from "has non false value" where the variables "are defined".

Comment: Sorry, I meant to check whether a variable is a non-falsey value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`any()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any), swapping your if and else clauses:

```
if any((foo, bar, baz)):
    do_something(foo, bar, baz)
else:
    raise SomeException
```

Answer (score 3):

Technically you're not checking for existence, you're checking for a non-falsey value (you'd get a `NameError` if the variable didn't exist).

That said, you could try this:

```
if any((foo, bar, baz)):
    do_something(foo, bar, baz)
else:
    raise SomeException
```

or this:

```
if not all((foo, bar, baz)):
    raise SomeException
else:
    do_something(foo, bar, baz)
```

depending on what you actually want, semantically.

Comment: `any()` and `all()` take 1 argument.